# Утечка памяти при использовании QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Заметил, что приложение стало "поедать" память. Начал отключать функционал, одну часть кода за другой. Осталась только отправка и обработка сетевых запросов к вебсерверу. Проверил через `valgrind`. Помимо привычных уведомлений об утечках (и их возможности) где ни попадя (как известно, фреймворк Qt многое тянет за собой), заметил, что ругается в том числе и на `QNetworkAccessManager`, а точнее на содержимое его метода `createRequest()`, который вызывается при каждом запросе в сеть:

```
==9662== 360,000 bytes in 5,000 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2,532 of 2,548
==9662==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9662==    by 0x54326A9: ??? (in /home/alexis/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.6.0)
==9662==    by 0x5432EFA: QObject::connect(QObject const*, char const*, QObject const*, char const*, Qt::ConnectionType) (in /home/alexis/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.6.0)
==9662==    by 0x4E9AB29: QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(QNetworkAccessManager::Operation, QNetworkRequest const&, QIODevice*) (in /home/alexis/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Network.so.5.6.0)
==9662==    by 0x4E984E3: QNetworkAccessManager::get(QNetworkRequest const&) (in /home/alexis/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Network.so.5.6.0)
==9662==    by 0x40174F: main (main.cpp:25)
```

И таких сообщений - море. Тогда собрал минимальный консольный проект, воспроизводящий проблему:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QTextStream>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtCore/QFile>
#include <QtCore/QUrl>

#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    int count = 0;

    QNetworkAccessManager *nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(&app);

    QFile file("test.txt");
    if(file.open(QFile::ReadOnly|QFile::Text)) {
        QTextStream stream(&file);

        while(!stream.atEnd()) {
            const QString url = stream.readLine().trimmed();

            QNetworkReply *reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));

            QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished
                , reply, &QNetworkReply::deleteLater);

            QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::destroyed, [&count]() {
                count -= 1;

                qDebug() << count;
            });

            count += 1;

            QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        }

        file.close();
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

К сожалению, этот код мало что может дать, если не использовать большое количество запросов. Они все берутся из текстового файла (в примере - "test.txt"), который был мною подготовлен заранее. Этот файл содержит 5000 ссылок. Как его приложить к вопросу, я не знаю, поэтому просто [ссылка на дропбокс](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l395u6hraw45vdq/test.txt?dl=0).

Счётчик `count` в коде примера показывает, что все объекты запросов гарантированно уничтожаются, однако даже если просто смотреть на показатели системного монитора или программы `top` (Linux), то забираемые 60 Мб ОЗУ по завершению работы по отправке запросов не освобождаются. Ну и конечно показания `valgrind`.

Пробовал по всякому закрывать (`close`), абортить (`abort`) и удалять объекты ответов (`QNetworkReply`), но к большому моему сожалению - нулевой эффект.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этой проблемой? Всё-таки сетевая часть - одна из самых часто используемых в Qt. Может быть я что-то не понимаю. Прошу помочь разобраться. По возможности и на виндовс, поскольку таковой рядом нет.

**Дополнение**

Добавил в код `malloc_trim(0)`:

```
        ...
        QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::destroyed, [&count]() {
            count -= 1;

            qDebug() << count;

            if(count == 0) {
                malloc_trim(0);
            }
        });
        ...
```

Количество занятой памяти уменьшилось с 60 Мб до 57 Мб. Программа, если не выполнять запросов занимает менее 1 Мб.

**Дополнение 2**

[QTBUG-30817 QNetworkAccessManager memory leaks](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-30817)

Comment: Попробуйте в Linux вызывать `malloc_trim(0)` после того, как память освободите(когда `count` в нуль опустится) и проверьте, что будет показывать top.

Comment: @ixSci , спасибо. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Странно, не должно быть проблем. Видимо Вас ждёт долгое время в обнимку с кучей разных утилит. Попробуйте ещё руками удалять `QNetworkReply`, которые из get возвращаются. Т.е. соберите их в кучу, а потом массово удалите и сделайте trim

Comment: @ixSci , попробовал, такая же беда. В сети ответ искал, многие с этой проблемой сталкивались (половина из них, правда, были сами виноваты), но решения нет.

Comment: еще посмотрите, чему равен размер кэша: `cache()->cacheSize();`, если он вообще выставлен в менеджере.

Comment: @ixSci , кэш не используется в менеджере по умолчанию (нулевой указатель на объект кэширования). Я в дополнение на всякий пожарный ещё выставлял к каждому запросу атрибут, чтобы исключительно без кэша отправлялся. Но без толку. Но хотя бы точно известно, что кэш тут ни причём.

Answer (score 1):

Вот этот кусок кода подозрителен:

```
QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished
                , reply, &QNetworkReply::deleteLater);
```

Дело в том, что сигнал `finished` испускает `QNetworkAccessManager` (см.[тут](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished)). Поэтому, имеет смысл получение данных или ошибки + `reply->deleteLater()` делать в собственном слоте. Но вышеприведенный `connect` привязать всеж по-другому (что-то типа [этого](http://itnotesblog.ru/note.php?id=250)). Могу ошибаться, проверить пока нет возможности.